# MYSQL Function throws custom error message instantly after creating it

Tags: mysql, function, signals

Hi hope you guys can help.

I am trying to throw an error Message inside a Function if the Input (INT) isn't equal to length 8.

My Code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test(a INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret INT;
    IF LENGTH(CONVERT(a, CHAR)) != 8 THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '4500' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'need to be 8!';
    END IF;
    IF a <= 20000000 THEN SET ret = 1;
    ELSEIF a > 20000000 AND a <= 30000000 THEN SET ret = 2;
    ELSE SET ret = 3;
    END IF;
    RETURN ret;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately when i create the Function it instantly throws the error message and doesn't wait for the condition. 
So when i am trying to run the Code it says:

```
Error Code: 1407. Bad SQLSTATE: '4500'
```

How can i solve that??

Comment: SQLSTATEs are 5-byte codes, you're trying to set up a 4-byte one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test(a INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret INT;
    IF LENGTH(CONVERT(a, CHAR)) != 8 THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'need to be 8!';   #--I had made changes at this line#
    END IF;
    IF a <= 20000000 THEN SET ret = 1;
    ELSEIF a > 20000000 AND a <= 30000000 THEN SET ret = 2;
    ELSE SET ret = 3;
    END IF;
    RETURN ret;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Try above code.
There is no `SQLSTATE`  with `4500`.Instead of `4500` you can try `45000` **`SQLSTATE`**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Sagnar Gangwal First of all thanks a lot for your answer. I was able to create the function. Unfortunately the condition doest work. If the input isn't equal to 8 the Function doesn't calculate `ret` wich is fine but it also doesn't throw the message `'need to be 8!'`. I tried calling the function using: `SELECT test(223941245)`. Do you maybe see the next dumb mistake i do? haha

Comment: @user7992920 I had tried same,and got proper error message as shown in below [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1mLt.png)

Comment: I think the ; after the end statement should be deleted. But otherwise it work for me too.

Comment: One correction: the SQLSTATE you can apply doesn't need to exist in the documentation, but needs to be **well-formed** (5-byte, with two alphanumeric characters and three number characters following). `45` is the class specifically for _user-defined_ SQLSTATEs, but the following number can be anything, not necessarily `000`. You can also use other classes, if you feel it's appropriate for your application; however keep in mind that they _might_ someday get reserved for some other system use.